# Getting currently date on a variable

Tags: c, string, date

I have a variable: `char date[11];`, and I need to put inside it the current date, for example `29/06/2012`.

So I'll do something like:

```
printf ("%s\n", date);
```

And the output would be: `29/06/2012`

I only found the option to print the date in words, like `Fri, June 2012`, but not the actual date in numbers.

So how can I print the current date in numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference this function [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). I'll let you figure out how to use it :-)

Since you claimed that you have searched for it, I'll provide the answer:

```
// first of all, you need to include time.h
#include<time.h>

int main() {

  // then you'll get the raw time from the low level "time" function
  time_t raw;
  time(&raw);

  // if you notice, "strftime" takes a "tm" structure.
  // that's what we'll be doing: convert "time_t" to "tm"
  struct tm *time_ptr;
  time_ptr = localtime(&raw);

  // now with the "tm", you can format it to a buffer
  char date[11];
  strftime(date, 11, "%d/%m/%Y", time_ptr);

  printf("Today is: %s\n", date);
}
```

Comment: I've searched like 3 pages of google of the function, and I just couldent find the solution...

Comment: I have added more to the answer. Refresh to see.

Comment: @AmitM9S6: You *really* need to get a hold of a decent C reference manual (my go-to resource is [C: A Reference Manual](http://www.careferencemanual.com/), 5th ed., by Harbison & Steele).  Don't just rely on the Web; most online C references (ones I've seen, anyway) range anywhere from "okay" to "don't touch with a barge pole".

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/), part of `time.h`. You'll need to pass it a `struct tm *`.

For your example, the format string would be: `"%d/%m/%Y"`, a pretty common case.

Based on code from the docs:

```
char date[11];
time_t t;
struct tm *tmp;

t = time(NULL);
tmp = localtime(&t);
if (tmp != NULL)
{
    if (strftime(date, 11, "%d/%m/%Y", tmp) != 0)
        printf("%s\n", date);
}
```